# Esperanto word formation ambiguity

Tags: word-formation

Estas skribita tio en PAG:

> Tio troviĝas precipe ĉe la largsignifaj sufiksoidoj AĴ, IL kaj UM: porkaĵo povas esti viando aŭ maldecaĵo, kovrilo povas rilati indiferente al tiel diversaj aferoj, kiel poto, lito aŭ libro; pafilo povas ĵeti ŝtonetojn aŭ kuglojn; buŝumo povas malhelpi hund-mordon aŭ helpi al tenado de objekto en la buŝo ktp.

Do, pri tio mi havas demandon. "Porkaĵo" ja estas la viando de la porko, sed kio se mi volus esprimi la duan signifon? Same por "acidigi", kiu signifas "igi acida", ne estas vorto por "igi acido", eble "acidaĵigi", sed mi ne scias, ĉu tiu certas pro la signifo de -AĴ-. Tio estas, antaŭ la forigo de la finaĵo antaŭ sufikso, kion oni faru se oni volas esprimi alian finaĵon ol la normala, kiel en "porkaĵo" aŭ "acidigi"? Kaj kiel oni diru "igi ŝtato" se "ŝtatigi" jam signifas *nationalize*?

Tiuj okazoj estas vere maloftaj, sed ili iufoje aperas. Same pri alia kazo priparolata en PAG: kiu estas la vicnumeralo de *kelke, multe*? Certe ne *kelka, multa* ĉar tiuj jam estas adjektivoj por kvantoj, ne vicpozicio.

La plej fama kazo estas "neebla", kiu signifas *impossible*, do oni devas diri "neadebla" por *deniable*.

Comment: Mi ne tute komprenas vian demandon, aŭ kiel oni propre respondus ĝin, sed mi diros, ke se per „igi acido,“ vi volus esprimi „kaŭzi ion esti acido,“ plej ofte la frazo „fari ion acido“ estas taŭga. Se io ekestas acido, oni tiel povas diri ke ĝi „fariĝis acido.“